# Split string containing comma with comma delimiter

Tags: string, split

Using std C++, I would like to split a string delimited by commas but ignore commas in strings that are surrounded by single quotes. For example:

1,'2,3',4,5,'6,7',8

when split becomes

```
1
'2,3'
4
5
'6,7'
8
```

I think this might be best handled with regex, but I'm not sure how to construct the pattern. Any solution without regex is welcome, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the C++ syntax would be, but here's some pseudocode:

```
vector<string> split(const string& value)
{
    bool is_escaped = false;
    vector<char> current;
    vector<string> result;

    for (char c : value)
    {
        if (c == '\'')
        {
            is_escaped = !is_escaped;
        }

        if (c == ',' && !is_escaped)
        {
            result.push_back(string(current.begin(), current.end());
            current.clear();
        }
        else
        {
            current.push_back(c);
        }
    }

    result.push_back(string(current.begin(), current.end());
    return result;
}
```

Obviously you'll need to adjust it to be valid C++ but it should do the trick.

Comment: Worked pretty much right out of the boxes with just a couple changes. I guess I need to familiarize myself more with the standard library. Thanks!